# How do I embed an image on twitter from my own website?

Tags: php, image, twitter

I have an generated image on my website using php and I want to have a "tweet this image" link which puts something like

> "This image was generated at `example.com`  on a twitter post.

How would that be possible?

I read that it's only possible to embed images from twitter servers themselves but is there a way to upload them automatically once the user clicks on "tweet this image"?

I currently have this:

```
<a class='fab fa-twitter' 
    target='_blank' 
    href='twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<img-link>" 
    . $player->getIgn() 
    . "&amp;via=<name>&amp;text=My%20first%20join%20on%20Hypixel%20was%20" 
    . $player->getYears()
    ."%20years%20ago!'>Tweet this image</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the Twitter markup guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/markup).

> `twitter:image`

> URL of image to use in the card. Images must be less than 5MB in size. JPG, PNG, WEBP and GIF formats are supported. Only the first frame of an animated GIF will be used. SVG is not supported.
> *Used with summary, summary_large_image, player cards.*

Example:

```html
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

Comment: Hm but how would the syntax look then?
I currently have this: <a class='fab fa-twitter' target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<img-link>" . $player->getIgn() . "&amp;via=<name>&amp;text=My%20first%20join%20on%20Hypixel%20was%20" . $player->getYears()."%20years%20ago!'>Tweet this image</a>

Comment: @austrianExpert Please file an [edit] to your original question with this info and everything else that helps understanding your question without reading comments. Also, please use Markdown syntax for formatting to enhance readability. Thanks! Just from looking at your snippet, I'd say you manually escaped the link? What CMS is this? Plain PHP? What is and does `$player->getIgn()` do and where does it come from, etc?